# Rails - superclass mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, model, routes

Playing with Rails and controller inheritance.

I've created a controller called `AdminController`, with a child class called `admin_user_controller` placed in `/app/controllers/admin/admin_user_controller.rb`

This is my routes.rb

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :admin_user # Have the admin manage them here.
  end
```

app/controllers/admin/admin_user_controller.rb

```
class AdminUserController < AdminController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

app/controllers/admin_controller.rb

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

end
```

I have a user model which I will want to edit with admin privileges.

When I try to connect to: `http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_user/`

I receive this error:

```
superclass mismatch for class AdminUserController
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To complete what @Intrepidd said, you can wrap your class inside a module, so that the `AdminUserController` class doesn't inherit twice from `ApplicationController`, so a simple workaround would be :

```
module Admin
  class AdminUserController < AdminController
    def index
      @users = User.all
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

This error shows up if you define two times the same class with different superclasses. Maybe try grepping `class AdminUserController` in your code so you're sure you're not defining it two times. Chances are there is a conflict with a file generated by Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a "Dashboard" controller and an "index" def. I then edited my routes.rb thusly:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do



namespace :admin do
    get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'

    resources :posts
end



end
```