# Rails: Test case is failing when running all the test cases simultaneously in rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine, minitest

I am running test case with rubymine. whenever i run individual test case it works and But one of my test case is failed whenever i run all the test cases simultaneously.

Below is the error that i am getting.

```
Fail to load: D:/image-resource-planning/test/models/fact_revenue_cost_test.rb:1
      Exception message: superclass mismatch for class FactRevenueCostTest
["D:/image-resource-planning/test/models/fact_revenue_cost_test.rb:4:in `(root)'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1065:in `require'", "C:/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'", "C:/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'", "C:/jruby-1.7.16/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'", "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 2016.2.4/rb/testing/runner/tunit_or_minitest_in_folder_runner.rb:1:in `(root)'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 2016.2.4/rb/testing/runner/tunit_or_minitest_in_folder_runner.rb:51:in `require_all_test_scripts'", "C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 2016.2.4/rb/testing/runner/tunit_or_minitest_in_folder_runner.rb:44:in `require_all_test_scripts'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1081:in `load'", "-e:1:in `(root)'"]
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346213/rails-superclass-mismatch

Comment: Have you tried running these test in the console to see if it is ruby mine specific?

Comment: No it was not specific to rubymine. The issue was coming because i had assigned same class name to two different classes. above link given by jcm helped me to figure out my problem.